# React component is picking the old state when used with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still getting a hang of hooks in React. I am making a tic tac toe game to understand the concept of the `useState` hook. Everything works fine but I need to make an extra move to find the winner. This is because I'm calling a function on every user move, and that function is unable to get the updated state, it always has one step older state of the game.

Here is the link to the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-paper-00u60?file=/src/App.js). Here is how the flow works:

- First Render: `Game` function calls -> `Board` function -> Board uses a custom hook, `useBoardState` -> `useBoardState` initializes an empty array of size 9 in the state, and returns array and a function `updateSquares` to update the state(+ there is some other stuff to render the UI but unrelated to the issue).
- When the user clicks on an empty box: `selectSquare` function gets called -> `selectSquare` calls `updateSquares` to update the state(+ some other stuff to make the game usable.)

Observe that the console in the `selectSquare` function has the stale state even when the `updateSquares` was executed. I was expecting that the state would be updated function was called.

As requested in the comments, I'm adding the relevant part of the code here:

```js
function useBoardState() {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(() => Array(9).fill(null));

  function updateSquares(index, mark) {
    setSquares((prevSquares) => {
      const newSquares = [...prevSquares];

      newSquares[index] = mark;

      return newSquares;
    });
  }

  return [squares, updateSquares];
}
```

I think it has something to do with this custom hook, I think the `updateSquares` state dispatcher updates the state when the render is complete.

not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: I don't really get what should be the expected result in your example :/

Comment: Let me add the relevant code here. Just wanted to provide a working example to help people :)

Comment: @johannchopin click on the empty button and observe in the console that both consoles have different values printed. To get a more clear picture, try to go through the whole flow, make one user win the game, and see that you have to make an extra move before the board gets disabled.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Of course the code works, please go through the question again. You will find what is the expected behavior and what's happening for now.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. But why do you refuse to provide a working example here on-site so everyone can help you, and so it's useful to people in the future? Again, please see [mcve] and [instructions for a React Stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The biggest reason for not using the SO snippet is that when I add the code, it says error at line 0, column 0, and filename "". There are other small reasons too: 1) No code auto-completion, 2) No auto code formatting, 3) No braces autocomplete, 4) No proper hints for code debugging. Using the codeSandbox, as it does a way better job for such things. I feel there's still a lot of essential stuff missing in the SO snippet editor at this time.

Comment: @BharatSoni - No question the snippet editor isn't **nearly** as good as it should be (I've brought that up with SE multiple times, as have others), but that's no reason to leave important parts of your question off-site. But it's not an IDE, it's a place to *paste* your code. If you [follow the instructions I've given you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/), you can create a working example mostly via copy-and-paste from your off-site resource (you just have to change some imports, etc.). You'd probably have an answer by now if you did that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree that the important parts of the question shouldn't be off-site. But it's too difficult to add a working snippet. I took your advice and tried to make a snippet. Like I mentioned in my previous comment, it shows a script error at line 0, column 0 in file "". The same code is working on sandbox but it is creating issues on SO. I spent some 15mn to debug, but couldn't figure out what was wrong. It's bad UX, I understand it's not an IDE, but it should provide the basic functionalities(at least braces auto-completion). People won't use the UI if with so many steps/hurdles.

Comment: @BharatSoni - I understand your frustration, it bothers me too. If you can't get a snippet working with the examples and instructions [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/), just include all relevant, necessary code in code blocks instead.. Keep in mind both the "minimal" and "reproducible" in [mcve]. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

the setter returned from `useState` as well as the class based component equivelant `setState` are not called synchronously. That is why if you do something like

```
const updateSomething = () => {
   setFoo(1)
   setBar(2)
   setFooBar(3)
   console.log('hey')
}
```

React will log `hey` before it starts setting the state, furthermore it will actually batch `setFoo`, `setBar` and `setFooBar` together, so it does a single rerender with all the above state updates.

Comment: ah, so it's similar to setState and gets called asynchronously. would it make sense to `await` for the state dispatcher to be executed and then check the state?

Comment: or do you know any other better way to solve such a problem...

Comment: If you need to perform actions on state updates, you can use the `useEffect` hook, it takes a callback as first argument, and an array of subscriptions as second, which when changed will trigger the callback